# How to get the data in dictionary list in Python?

Tags: python

I know there are similar topics on Stack Overflow but I don't understand them deeply. Here what I get from other:

```
list=[{'i1': 'ultimate'},{'i2': 'dom'},{'i3': 'free'}]
get=input("")
search = [s for s in list if get in s]
print (search)
```

I don't really get how the search works. Could you give me an enlightenment in this code?

Here is my problem: (very simple one compare the other search)

```
for n in range(len(list)):
  get=input("")
  for i in list:
    print (i[get])
```

I have this code but it give me error, it only take if there is multiple same string.

```
OUTPUT:
in: i1
out: ultimate
in: i3
out: free
in: i2
out: dom
```

More different ways the better, in order compare with my own work and help other with same problem as mine. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I have no idea what the question is... what is your input and what is your output?

Comment: 'Search' is list comprehension of python.

Comment: Please do not call a variable `list` -- you overwrite the function by the same name.

Answer (score -1):

From your code my understand is that your array is missing the key you are looking for. So first check if it exists or not.

```
list=[{'i1': 'ultimate'},{'i2': 'dom'},{'i3': 'free'}]
get=input()
for i in list:
    if get in i:
       print(i[get])
```

Comment: The downvotes may be from the first version, where there was no explanation added.